# How to Check if NodeJs Main Thread is doing too much heavy task or not?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am running my NodeJs app on Google App Engine and as NodeJs handles requests in a single-threaded environment that's why I wanted to ask is there any way to check if my NodeJs Main thread is doing heavy tasks or not ??

Answer (score 0):

The app http://pm2.keymetrics.io/ has many monitoring features that can detect the health of nodejs and take specified actions.